# Is there way to use ls cmd to list out all file with specific string in random location of the filename?

Tags: linux, command-line

I can't find any way to list out files with specific string in random location of the filename, except "find" command.

I don't want to use find command, it is very complicated to me.

for example:
I want to list out files with "def" inside the filename no matter where the specified string is located.
aa234aaaaaaaaadefaaaaa42.txt
defaaaaaaaa234.txt
aaaa234aadef.txt

Is there way to achieve this with our common "$ls" command ?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With find:

`find . -name "*def*"`

with fd

`fd def`

With ls

`ls ./*def*`

Note that ls won't go thru subdirectories, you will need to search **each and every** directory manually.

Comment: Wonderful.. This is want i have being looking.. You are the 1st one that provide this.. Could be there are other ppl, but i just didn't manage to find them. All i saw was "find" command which i don't want.  $ls ./*def* did the trick. Thanks so much. !!

Comment: Note that sooner or later you `will` need find. It is a very handy and very powerful tool and it is worth the 10 minutes to get to know its syntax.

Comment: I knew the syntax. learnt it long time ago, but I keep forgetting it when i needed it.. :-)